# Not able to install IPA from a developer

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have hired an iphone developer overseas to develop and iphone app for me. The dev sent me the IPA. I tried installing it using iFunBox and even using IPA installer and it keeps failing. I even tried iTunes and it kept failing. I tried it on both jailbroken and none-jailbroken devices

The developer is telling me that he can see it on it has to go on the developer account and he is requesting the dev account credential
My questions are:

1- Why do you think the IPA is not getting installed properly (I was able to install different apps IPA so I know my installers work!).

2- Is giving the dev account credential the norm?   I come from android development and for us, you give a signed APK with the user keystore and your are done!

Please assist
Thank you

Comment: You need to provide more details. Is the developer account an enterprise one? Is he using an ad hoc provisioning profile?

Comment: Use www.diawi.com  simple, easy and elegant.

Comment: Just ask your developer to make sure that, ad-hoc provisioning profile he is using while making build, have your iPhone/iPad/iPod's UDID registered..!! Dats it..

Comment: Or next time hire me :P :P

Comment: Hmm.  Thank you. I will check what provisioning file they are using

Comment: You did not provide enough information. For someone to even _begin_ to be able to help you, you'd need to include any errors that you have encountered. (`it kept failing` gives us no useful information)

Comment: I wish there is an error code I can share. When I tried on iTunes (sync and apply) ,it just says "installing". If I try with iFunBox or IPA installer, it says "Application could not be installed".

Comment: You need to add your device uuid in provisioning profile .. and with that selected provisioning your dev need to generate ipa , then only it will work on your device .. its not android bro ... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do the steps :

1. create a (.csr) certification signing request file from ur mac (keychain access) and create developer's certificate from member's portal apple.

2.add your device uuid .

3.Create Provisioning Profile adding that device .

4.download that provisioning profile and send the cert and provisioning to the dev , and tell him to double tap both .

[OR]

-- Use teamViewer and sign in to ur developer's XCODE with ur app id ...

-- Go to Xcode preferences and select account and refresh .

-- select the provisioning profile and cert from build settings and build the project with that provisionings ..

Use that ipa to install and it wont deny ..

make comment if you're having problem ...

Comment: i am getting problem in android , if you can help i will be thankful .. by the way i know ios and generating android app first time ... 

Problem is related array adaptor ...

Comment: Sure I can help, you can ask it here or better create a question and I will answer it.. Just put the link if the question here.  And Btw, what I meant for "hire you" is to hire you for my ios project

Comment: are you referring to the same question you posted? Because the answer posted seemed good and not exactly sure what the problem you are facing. If different then Yea i can help

Comment: Another problem : you mean same question or is it different question. Please point me to where the problem is

Comment: I need to compile pjsip for android ... can you give me skype that i can discuss my problem ?

Comment: I actually never used it. You know Android has soooo many libraries and I am familiar with the native SDK mostly. I could share Skype, but don't want the whole world to see it :)

Comment: I have created the project with native sip AIP's by android but all devices are not able to use the API.

Comment: I actually don't know about SIP. The only thing that comes to mind, make sure you check the library under "Build Path-> export" when build you project

Comment: ok thanks and if any projects you want me to do .. please inform me

Comment: how can I reach you? :)

Comment: Hiiii Snake , Hows it going ?